# Which JavaScript event gets fired, when there's div refresh ( no content change in DOM) by an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Yes an Ajax call in my code, just highlights the div without changing any content, though change in the inline style attribute of the div is seen.

Can't use `:success` option of Ajax as the call is packed in a plugin.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Short answer is that there is no such event, longer answer would mutation observers, but unless you know what you're doing, you'd be better of just doing your own thing when the ajax call is completed.

Comment: If you know which action makes the ajax call, you got your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach to the [ajaxComplete event](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) on the Document object, this will fire when any ajax call in your page has finished.